# Showing equivalence of expressions for the joint probability of two events

Tags: probability, statistics

If I have random variable $v$ distributed by CDF $G$ on $[\underline{v},\bar{v}]$, I know that $Pr(v\geq a-x \hspace{1mm} and \hspace{1mm} v\geq a)=Pr(v\geq a-x | v  \geq a)Pr(v\geq a)= Pr(v\geq a)$, where $x$ is non-negative. But I cannot seem to get the same answer if instead I write $Pr(v\geq a | v\geq a-x)Pr(v\geq a-x)$. These two should clearly be equivalent. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\ge 0$, then clearly
$$
\{v\ge a-x\}\cap\{v\ge a\}=\{v\ge a\},
$$
and so, the probability of these events is the same.

If you, nevertheless, want to use conditioning,
$$
\mathsf{P}(v\ge a\mid v\ge a-x)=\frac{\mathsf{P}(v\ge a)}{\mathsf{P}(v\ge a-x)},
$$
assuming that the denominator is positive, so that you get the same result.